# Is the result $|\text{rank(AB)}-\text{rank(BA)}| \le \text{min}(\text{rank}(A),\text{rank}(B))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Is the result $|\text{rank(AB)}-\text{rank(BA)}| \le \text{min}(\text{rank}(A),\text{rank}(B))$ true for all $n*n$ matrices $A,B$.
I only know the result that $\text{rank(AB)} \le \text{min(rank(A),rank(B))}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Your desired inequality is a consequence of the one you mentioned. In other words, it follows from the fact that the ranks of both $AB$ and $BA$ are non-negative integers at most equal to that minimum.

Comment: Yes, it's really just a question about integer arithmetic!